# Failed to Deploy to Heroku Platform

Tags: python, heroku, pyodbc

I am creating a html web form, from which I want the data to be stored into the local machine. While running the program it works fine on my local machine.

When I push the program to Heroku platform it fails.

```
   ----main file
   -------Procfile
   -------requirements.txt
   -------runtime.txt
   -------main.py
   -------static
   ----templates
   ------index.html
   ----static
   ------index_css.css
```

Procfile:

```
     web: gunicorn main:app
```

Requirements:

```
    flask==1.1.1
    flask-mysqldb==0.2.0
    gunicorn==19.9.0
    pyodbc==4.0.30
```

Runtime:

```
    python-3.7.2
```

Error While Deploying it on Heroku PLatform:

```
    Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): started
     Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
      command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-q2igx1jr/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-q2igx1jr/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-8r1wqs6z
          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-q2igx1jr/pyodbc/
     Complete output (16 lines):
     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
       warnings.warn(msg)
     running bdist_wheel
     running build
     running build_ext
     building 'pyodbc' extension
     creating build
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
     gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
     In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
     src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
      #include <sql.h>
               ^~~~~~~
     compilation terminated.
     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
     ----------------------------------------
     ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
     Running setup.py clean for pyodbc
     Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py): started
     Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
     Created wheel for mysqlclient: filename=mysqlclient-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl size=100868 sha256=ffd0776f2d39a5405cc1ac1465a08f48ee9da558c172105866f17378a6edebbd
     Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-5xsag9fy/wheels/80/87/ff/4ea9d03e0a265ef3a4a0cdf0cf1e4786c37665c4015b2ece83
   Successfully built flask-mysqldb mysqlclient
   Failed to build pyodbc
   Installing collected packages: Werkzeug, click, itsdangerous, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, flask, mysqlclient, flask-mysqldb, gunicorn, pyodbc
       Running setup.py install for pyodbc: started
       Running setup.py install for pyodbc: finished with status 'error'
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-q2igx1jr/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-q2igx1jr/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-oz00635z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m/pyodbc
            cwd: /tmp/pip-install-q2igx1jr/pyodbc/
       Complete output (16 lines):
       /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
         warnings.warn(msg)
       running install
       running build
       running build_ext
       building 'pyodbc' extension
       creating build
       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
       gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.30 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
       In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
       src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
        #include <sql.h>
                 ^~~~~~~
       compilation terminated.
       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
       ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-q2igx1jr/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-q2igx1jr/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-oz00635z/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m/pyodbc Check the logs for full command output.
Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
Push failed
```

I am fairly new to Heroku and I don't know how to solve this error.

Comment: you have to create an `env` folder which must contain all the dependicies which are used in your project for example `flask` `numpy` etc watch this video to get an idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1P8B53CCxs

Comment: I created a requirements.txt file that contains all the dependencies, then why create an env again?

Comment: I followed the video and I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

in Procfile you can change:
web: gunicorn main.wsgi